# Eclipse Git (egit) pull and push to upstream option not available some times.?

Tags: eclipse, git, contextmenu, push, egit

Right click on Project -> Team -> push and pull not available(EGIT)

Eclipse pull and push to upstream option not available some times.? 
i am able to see commit every time but push ,pull,remote are missing some times
How to make appear them always

Answer (score 2):

Basically your eclipse is disconnected with git.

Right click on project -> Team -> share Project -> Select Repository type as git  -> Next -> chose your project and finish.

Answer (score 2):

For me this disappeared as well, while the .git/config is unchanged and good.

Refresh did not help.
But Eclipse restart did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The options disappear sometime if the EGIT is not able to find the path from which it should Fetch, Pull and Push.

Check if the origin is deleted.

Goto the GIT Repositories View

See for the Remotes -> origin

If the Push and Pull in origin are deleted. You will have to add the URI by right click on the origin, add origin and configuring the Push and Fetch URI.

[image]

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a frequent annoyance.  If Refresh doesn't work, I use "Close Project" followed by opening it again.